# Generic way to sort a linked list with considering 3 parameters in C

Tags: c

i have simple linked list with this struct:

```
typedef struct exam {
    char name[100];
    int credits;
    int grade;
    struct exam* next;
} Exam;
```

I want to sort it in lexicographical way considering: The name sorted in alphabetic way, the credits and the grade sorted in a crescent way

Both credits and grade are positive and can assume any dsired number.

How would you do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare each field in priority order and assign an ordering based on that.  For example:

```
int cmp_examp(Exam *e1, Exam *e2)
{
    if (strcmp(e1->name, e2->name) < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (strcmp(e1->name, e2->name) > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (e1->credits < e2->credits) {
        return -1;
    } else if (e1->credits > e2->credits) {
        return 1;
    } else if (e1->grade < e2->grade) {
        return -1;
    } else if (e1->grade > e2->grade) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This orders exams first by name, then by credits, then by grade.

Comment: Yeah I was think about sorting using counting sort because it's a stable algorithm, the problem is that I don't know how to use it in a linked list, only on an array...

Comment: Maybe you can show a code or pseudo code of how you would implement it? I would be very grateful :)

Comment: @androidexpert35 So your question isn't about ordering this specific struct but about sorting and linked list handling in general.  That's a bit too broad for this site.  Make an attempt, then come back with *specific* questions.

Comment: Hello, actually my question is about THIS struct I only want to understand better the reasoning you did. If I get it right this function will let me increase or decrease the priority of an Exam node over another but I'm not pretty sure

Comment: @androidexpert35 This function creates an ordering of exams.  It returns -1 if the the first operand is less than the second, 1 if the first is greater than the second, or 0 if they are equal.