# qsort on complex struct for lexicographical order

Tags: c

i've been making a program which contains array of this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char sigla[100];
    int crediti;
    int grado;
} Exam;
```

To compare it in qsort i made this comparison function:

```
int compare_exams(const void*a, const void*b)
{

  Exam *e1 = (Exam *)a;
  Exam *e2 = (Exam*)b;

    if (strcmp(e1->sigla, e2->sigla) < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (strcmp(e1->sigla, e2->sigla) > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (e1->crediti < e2->crediti) {
        return -1;
    } else if (e1->crediti > e2->crediti) {
        return 1;
    } else if (e1->grado < e2->grado) {
        return -1;
    } else if (e1->grado > e2->grado) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then call qsort like this:

```
    Exam exam_list[n];
// before calling it i make the insertion of elements using a for
    qsort(exam_list,k,sizeof(Exam),compare_exams);
```

now the problem is that the program just prints nothing as output and yeah i checked the print function and it's working flawessly

Maybe i should modify the compare function?
let me know!

thank you

Comment: What is `k`? Have you tried passing `n`?

Comment: "i made this comparison function:" looks like   [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61844800/2410359) answer and taking credit for other's work.